# Can't upload multiple images with formset

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms, formset

I have django app and problem with multiple images upload.
Everything was OK till add to Familymember model field `image`.
Now I can not create any item for FamilyMember.

Please for help.

Here is my model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile-update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)


class FamilyMember(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="localefile/")
    relationship = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Here are forms:

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        exclude = ()


class FamilyMemberForm(ModelForm):
    file = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))

    class Meta:
        model = FamilyMember
        exclude = ()


FamilyMemberFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Profile, FamilyMember,
                                            form=FamilyMemberForm, extra=1)
```

Here are my views, to create.

```
class ProfileCreate(CreateView):
    model = Profile
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']


class ProfileFamilyMemberCreate(CreateView):
    model = Profile
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile-list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(ProfileFamilyMemberCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['familymembers'] = FamilyMemberFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['familymembers'] = FamilyMemberFormSet()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        familymembers = context['familymembers']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if familymembers.is_valid():
                familymembers.instance = self.object
                familymembers.save()
        return super(ProfileFamilyMemberCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

I also use a JavaScript code, from [here](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'formset/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.formset_row').formset({
        addText: 'add family member',
        deleteText: 'remove',
        prefix: 'familymember_set'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload?

Comment: @MHassan not yet, please tell me because topic is difficult, can I with this tool create multiupload with formset?

Comment: This package is for uploading multiple files. Like you have one file field and you can select multiple files in that file field and all selected files will be saved once you save form. I have used it for uploading multiple files a long time ago.

Comment: The `file` attribute of `FamilyMember` holds one single file, how will it store multiple files? Which database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

When you upload a file it's passed through request.FILES, so you must also pass it to you FormSet, e.g:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(ProfileFamilyMemberCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['familymembers'] = FamilyMemberFormSet(
                data=self.request.POST,
                files=self.request.FILES
           )
        else:
            data['familymembers'] = FamilyMemberFormSet()
        return data
```

Don't forget to add the enctype in your form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ...>
```